# MVC Delete Action Link Not Working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.actionlink

My Action link looks like so:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Delete Message", "DeleteMessage", new { messageId=item.MESSAGEID })%>
```

And my Action in my controller looks like so:

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Delete)]
    public ActionResult DeleteMessage(int messageId)
    {

        Message message = context.Messages.FirstOrDefault(m => m.MESSAGEID.Equals(messageId));
        if (message != null)
        {
            context.Messages.DeleteOnSubmit(message);
            context.SubmitChanges();
        }
        return View();
    }
```

But for some reason, the item in my model still does not get deleted. Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ActionLink` produces an `a` element with a link which is accessed with standard `GET` request. Your action, however, explicitly specifies that it expects `DELETE` method, hence it never actually gets invoked.

Moreover, no "destructive" actions should be performed with `GET` requests. See [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2010/01/08/implementing-a-delete-link-with-mvc-2-and-httpmethodoverride.aspx) on implementing "delete" link.

Answer (score 1):

`ActionLink` (i.e. `a` html tag) sends a `GET` request rather then `DELETE`, so your action is not mapped to the request.

You can [use Ajax](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2009/01/21/asp.net-mvc-tip-46-ndash-donrsquot-use-delete-links-because.aspx) to perform DELETE request (see “Performing Ajax Deletes” section).